# codeigniter - my user gets logged out whenever i click the update cart button

Tags: codeigniter

Whenever I want to update the quantity of the item in my cart, the account gets logged out and the cart loses all its items but when I update my cart when I'm not logged in, the items stay.

`cart/update` controller file

```
public function update($in_cart = null) 
{
   $data = $_POST;
   $this->cart->update($data);
   //show cart page
   redirect('cart','refresh');
}
```

Comment: Are you utilising session correctly?

Comment: Almost certainly a session and/or cookies configuration issue.